# NoReverseMatch at Django

Tags: python, django

and I do not know why and what will be the problem, could they help me? Thanks beforehand, greetings!

```
Reverse for 'entregado' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'cod_experto': 'ASE-0048', 'id_pedido': 1770}' not found. 1 pattern(s)      tried: ['solicitar/confirmar/(?P<id_pedido>\\d+)/(?P<cod_experto>\\d+)/$']
```

Error during template rendering admindata.html, error at line 74:

```
<td><a href="{% url "usuario:entregado" id_pedido=ped.id cod_experto=ped.articulo.cod_experto  %}" method='GET' type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="editar" onclick="document.location.reload();"/>Entregar</a></td>
```

url global:

```
urlpatterns = [
# Examples:
url(r'^solicitar/', include(urls, namespace="usuario")),
]
```

url APP:

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^confirmar/(?P<id_pedido>\d+)/(?P<cod_experto>\d+)/$', login_required(Update_stock), name='entregado'),
]
```

and views.py:

```
def Update_stock(request, id_pedido, cod_experto):
if request.method == 'GET':
   pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=id_pedido)
   articulo = Articulo.objects.get(id=cod_experto)
   articulo.stock -= pedido.cantidad
   stock.save()
return render(request, 'admindata.html', {'pedido':pedido, 'articulo':articulo})
```

Comment: You'll need to post the `import` statements for the global `urls`. Can't see anything wrong in what you've already posted.

Comment: The global url is not the problem since they work perfectly with others I have, except that I throw that mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cod_experto` value is "ASE-0048", which does not match the regex `\d+` - that only matches integers.

If you want to be able to accept values like that, you need to change your regex:

```
r'^confirmar/(?P<id_pedido>\d+)/(?P<cod_experto>[\w-]+)/$',
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. You're a genius.